# Switch between IFRAME's urls onclick button

Tags: javascript, html, css

Swap between the IFRAME addresses with the click of a button.

```html
<iframe src="www.example.com"></iframe>


<div id="2">
<iframe src="www.wow.com"></iframe>
```

Comment: Swap between 2 _iframes_ or change the _src_ in 1 frame?

Comment: Swap between 2 iframes

Comment: Do you mean to the content?

Comment: לא אני מתכוון לקישור.

Comment: להחליף בין שתי הכתובות של ה-IFRAME

Answer (score 1):

See here(run the code):https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FT3NWLA87A5A

```js
function func(){
var url1 = document.getElementById("frame1").src;
var url2 = document.getElementById("frame2").src;
document.getElementById("frame1").src=url2;
 document.getElementById("frame2").src=url1;
}
```

```html
<iframe src="https://www.w3schools.com" id="frame1">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
<iframe src="https://www.findertoday.com" id="frame2">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>

<button onclick="func()">Switch</button>
```

Comment: that what you mean?

Comment: לא עובד לי. הם לא מחליפים ביניהם

Comment: wait i will check it out can you add fiddle or something

Comment: Happy to help you:) dude;)